# sed to remove lines with pattern and that end in odd digit

Tags: regex, sed

In the `sed` below I am trying to remove all lines that have `ID_` and end in an odd number. Both of the commands execute but return the file unchanged.

**file**

```
ID_0111 xxx
ID_0112 xxx
ID_0113 xxx
ID_0114 xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**desired**

```
ID_0112 xxx
ID_0114 xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**sed**

```
sed '/ID_[13579]/d' file.txt
sed 's|ID_[13579]$| |g'
```

Comment: You need to add `-i` if you want the original file edited in-place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
sed '/^ID_[^ ]*[13579] /d' file

ID_0112 xxx
ID_0114 xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Here regex pattern `/^ID_[^ ]*[13579] /` matches a line that starts with `ID_` followed by 0 or more non-space characters and ends with `[13579]` before matching a space.

Or else, using `awk` you can do this:

```bash
awk '$1 !~ /^ID_/ || $1 ~ /[02468]$/' file

ID_0112 xxx
ID_0114 xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 3):

There can by any digit(s) before the odd one, and the odd one must be followed by a space.

```
sed '/ID_[0-9]*[13579] /d'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) like so:

```
grep -P -v '^ID_\d*[13579]\s' in_file > out_file
```

Here, `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-v` : Print lines that do **not** match.

The regex has:

`^` : matches the beginning of the line.
`\d*` : 0 or more digits.
`[13579]` : any odd digit.
`\s`: whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F_ '!(/^ID_/ && $2%2)' file
ID_0112 xxx
ID_0114 xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```